# Unable to arrange monitors on top of each-other for 6 monitor setup in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 22.04, video, ubuntu-gnome

I  have a 6 monitor setup with Ubuntu 22.04. I finally got ubuntu to even recognize them by installing the NVIDIA Quadro P620 drivers manually from the website via this method shown below. Before removing noveau and installing NVIDIA only 1 monitor would show up.

*disable current video*

```
$ sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
$ sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"

Confirm the content of the newly created modeprobe file blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf:

$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0

Enter the following Linux command to update kernel initramfs:

$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

*install new video*

```
$ sudo telinit 3

$ sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.94.run

$ sudo reboot
```

Now I have 6 monitors showing up in my display as seen in this screen shot. I was able to arrange them in one line but not on top of each-other.

[image]

This is not ideal because the first 3 monitors are on the bottom and the next 3 are mounted on top of the first 3.

Instead they should be arranged like this:

[image]

I also thought maybe nobody was answering this question because they have no idea why I need them arranged this way, I need them arranged this way because:

top row left = 2 | top row middle = 3 | top row right = 5

bottom row left = 1 | bottom row middle = 6 | bottom row right = 4

See pic if any questions:

[image]

However once I apply these changes, the monitors will do all kinds of weird things like clone each-other - some will randomly shut off at times. It is completely random but applying the changes never works and always shuts down some displays and or clones some monitors to other monitors.

Is there something I can do to get the monitors to be arranged in the same layout that they are physically installed in? In ubuntu 16 I was able to get it working with great pain of arranging them all the time and keeping a copy of monitors.xml yet it was never stable but it did work.

See screen shot of what happens to the monitors once I hit apply as an example:

[image]

If i try to re-arrange them here it wont apply, some are shut down and some are mirrored to others. The only way to get back to normal now is a reboot.

Then I hit revert so it won't break my setup in the line of monitors on one row by saving over the file that stores the good settings and it does this, it shuts down 2 of the monitors - I cant turn them back on now either. Now I will be rebooting to get it back to normal which at least works when I reboot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the `nvidia-driver-525` from the Ubuntu repos?